# Creating three threads in Java to compute three different items

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write my solution to a problem of multithreading in Java:

> Create three separate threads that will calculate the average, minimum
>   and maximum of a series of numbers that is passed to the program. The
>   values will be stored globally in the program. The three threads will
>   return the three values respectively to the main program where it will
>   be output to the user.

I'm new to Java, so I've got one basic question about the approach to this program: How do I create three separate threads that will perform ***three different functions***? While reading multithreading, I've come across several examples wherein three(or more) threads were created which would each execute a single function: `counting down a loop`. Thus requires only a single call to `public void run()` and one can very easily create three instances of a class that implements Runnable to do this, something like:

```
// Create multiple threads.
       class NewThread implements Runnable {
         String name; // name of thread
         Thread t;
         NewThread(String threadname) {
           name = threadname;
           t = new Thread(this, name);
           System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
           t.start(); // Start the thread
}
         // This is the entry point for thread.
         public void run() {
          try {
             for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
               System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
               Thread.sleep(1000);
             }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println(name + "Interrupted");
}
           System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
         }
}

  class MultiThreadDemo {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
         new NewThread("One"); // start threads
         new NewThread("Two");
         new NewThread("Three");
         try {
           // wait for other threads to end
           Thread.sleep(10000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
}
         System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
       }
}
```

I am not sure how to create threads that perform separate functions: calculate double, min and max. So far, I've created one thread that calculates the average and returns it to the main program. This is my code [till now]:

```
package assignment2;
class Q2Thread implements Runnable {


    String name;
    Thread t;
    private int average;
    int sum=0;

    Q2Thread(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
        t=new Thread(this, name);
        //System.out.println("This thr");
        t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<Q7Main.arr.length;i++)
                sum+=Q7Main.arr[i];

            average=sum/Q7Main.arr.length;



        }
        //catch(InterruptedException e)
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Calcuated average.");
        }

    System.out.println("Child Thread exiting.");
    }

    public int getAverage() 
    {
        return average;
    }

}

package assignment2;
import java.util.*;
public class Q7Main {

     public static int[] arr=new int[5];

    static Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int finalAverage;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("Please enter the numbers: " );
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++)
            arr[i]=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered the numbers: ");
        for(int x: arr)
            {
            System.out.print(x+ " ");
            }
        System.out.println();

        Q2Thread obj=new Q2Thread("Average");

        try
        {
            obj.t.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Interrupted.");
        }

        finalAverage=obj.getAverage();
        System.out.println("The average of the numbers is: "+ finalAverage);
    }

}
```

I have two questions now:

1. Can someone give me the approach to creating two more threads that will compute the min and max?
2. Are there any OOP defects in my code(thus far) that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create two other classes that calculate min and max, create an object of each of them `obj1` and `obj2`. Since the constructor starts the thread for you, you should now have 3 threads running asynchronously.

Call `obj1.t.join()` and `obj2.t.join()` within that try block. So it should look like this:

```
   try{
        obj.t.join();
        obj1.t.join();
        obj2.t.join();
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e)
   {
       System.out.println("Interrupted.");
   } 
   int average = obj.getAverage();
   int max = obj1.getMax();
   int min = obj2.getMin();
```

And then do whatever you want with these numbers.

As for some general comments, firstly I would not have a thread object as an attribute within the runnable class, nor have the `start()` method within the constructor. Instead, within the main class, I would encourage you to create three thread objects with an instance of each runnable class, and then invoke the `start()` method on each of them. Furthermore, instead of the three runnable 
classes all interacting with the same static array found in `Q7Main`, I would instead update their
constructors to accept the array as a parameter in the constructor, and then have each of them interact with a unique array object when their run method is invoked. Otherwise, you have an issue that when one thread changes the value of something in the array, you get unexpected results.

Of course in this case none of your classes do that, but its something to keep in mind.

For example

```
Q2Thread obj =new Q2Thread("Average", arr);
Q2MaxThread obj1 = new Q2MaxThread("Maximum", arr);
Q2MinThread obj2 = new Q2MinThread("Minimum", arr);
Thread avThread = new Thread(obj);
Thread maxThread = new Thread(obj1);
Thread minThread= new Thread(obj2);

avThread.start();
maxThread.start();
minThread.start();

   try{
        avThread.join();
        maxThread.join();
        minThread.join();
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e)
   {
       System.out.println("Interrupted.");
   } 
   int average = obj.getAverage();
   int max = obj1.getMax();
   int min = obj2.getMin();
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to the  @ElvenAshwin answer you should probably take three classes as private inner class.... good practice as you build bigger things you dont pollute public api. As an alternate and good exercise, think about doing it with lambdas in java 8. Its just a function you need not the class.